# "Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges" after passing pd.qcut duplicates='drop' kwarg

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` with hundreds of thousands of rows, and am creating a new dataframe which only contains the top quantile of rows for some group of values:

```
quantiles = (df.groupby(['Person', 'Date'])['Value'].apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 4, labels=[0, 0.25, 0.5, 1], duplicates='drop')))
```

When I run it, I get:

```
ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges
```

After trying to change the number of `bins` to `5` I still get the same error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don’t specify the labels. With dropping duplicates you cannot guarantee the number of bins that are returned, so trying to label them with a list of fixed length leads to errors.

Comment: Ah I see. But then how would I select the top quantile afterwards? Previously I had: `top_quantile_df = df[quantiles.eq(1)]`, but after I drop the `labels` argument I get `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: If you do `labels=False` it will label them with integers starting from `0`. You’d then need to mask by the max per group afterwards

Comment: Sorry but not sure I follow what you mean by mask by max per group. I don't really need a max limit on each group/bin—really only want the top `Value` quantile for that specific group.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue and I did this to overcome it.

bins = number of times the data is being sliced

labels = the range you are categorizing using labels.

> This error appears when labels > bins

follow these steps:

Step. 1: Don't pass labels initially

```
train['MasVnrArea'] = pd.qcut(train['MasVnrArea'],
                          q=5,duplicates='drop')
```

This will result in:

```
(-0.001, 16.0]     880
(205.2, 1600.0]    292
(16.0, 205.2]      288
Name: MasVnrArea, dtype: int64
```

Step 2:

Now we can see there are only three categories which are possible on binned.
So, assign labels accordingly. In my case, it is 3. So I am passing 3 labels.

```
bin_labels_MasVnrArea = ['Platinum_MasVnrArea', 
                         'Diamond_MasVnrArea','Supreme_MasVnrArea']
train['MasVnrArea'] = pd.qcut(train['MasVnrArea'],
                              q=5,labels=bin_labels_MasVnrArea,duplicates='drop')
```

Please watch this video on bins for a clear understanding.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HofOMf8RgjM
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because, after removing duplicates form some of the groups, the passed label size is more than the number of cut params you have passed. You have to make it dynamic something like wherever it's arising generate labels that much only.

Method : 1

```
df.groupby(key)['sales'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, min(len(x),3), labels=range(1,min(len(x),3)+1), duplicates = 'drop'))
```

here I'm making max 3 cut but if not possible make at least 1 or 2

Mathod : 2

```
import pandas as pd
df['rank'] = df.groupby([key])[sales].transform(lambda x: x.rank(method = 'first'))

def q_cut(x, cuts):
    unique_var = len(np.unique([i for i in x]))
    labels1 = range(1, min(unique_var,cuts)+1)
    output = pd.qcut(x, min(unique_var,cuts), labels= labels1, duplicates = 'drop')
    return output

df.groupby([key])['rank'].transform(lambda x: q_cut(x,10))`
```

Answer (score 0):

follow up with Amit Bidlan's answer, if we want the labels to be "int" instead of the origin "string of range", because of some drawing reasons,

i would do like this:

```
train['range_ori'] = pd.qcut(train['MasVnrArea'], q=5, duplicates='drop')
grouplist = train["range_ori"].unique().tolist()
grouplist.sort()
group_mapping = {g:i for i, g in enumerate(grouplist)}
train['group'] = train['range_ori'].apply(lambda x: group_mapping[x])
```

the advantage is you can handle dynamic bins length and no need to check it before setting the label~